# MYSQL Error #1064 - Update multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to update a dynamic form where the user can add, deleted and update questions in a questionnaire. I've created all my code that will generate one query which is executed once at the end.

I get a problem when I try to **update more than one question** at the same time (INSERT and DELETE works like a charm).

```
$query = ''; // append every thing to update in this variable
// for each questions check if needs to be modify, if yes append.
$query .= 'UPDATE `questionnaire` SET `id_category` = '.$categoryValue.' WHERE `id` = '.$idQuestion.'; '
```

Example of an output

```
UPDATE `questionnaire` SET `id_category` = 1 WHERE `id` = 1; UPDATE `questionnaire` SET `id_category` = 3 WHERE `id` = 2;
```

Submit to the database;

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

If I only have one UPDATE, it works like a charm. As soon that I have 2 updates, I get this MYSQL error :

```
errno : 1064
error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `questionnaire` SET `id_category` = 3 WHERE `id` = 2' at line 1
```

Does anyone have an idea why it only happens when I have two UPDATE ? If yes, how should I fix this.

Comment: Because you can only execute one statement at a time

Comment: `mysqli_prepare()` only supports one query at a time. Either make two calls or look at using `mysqli_multi_query()`. Reference is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: @juergend Thank you, I though we could execute more than one statement at a time when we use the prepare statement. So I guess I'll have send a query for each of my update.

Comment: ***Warning: SQL Injection Attack risk.*** Please read [this](http://bobby-tables.com) for additional information.

Comment: @K-Jtan Since you're assembling your query with concatenation there's no point in using `mysqli_prepare()`. If your data is trustworthy then `mysqli_multi_query()` is fine.

Comment: @MikeW Yes I tested out (didn't saw your comment the first time). I'll update the solution and mark as resolved. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MikeW `mysqli_multi_query()` will exacerbate the SQL Injection Attack risk

Comment: @Barranka Yes I am aware of this. Every value is checked to see if it's a possible value (I didn't want to put my 300 lines of code here). Thank you for the warning

Comment: @Barranka We don't know that there is a risk. We don't know where the data comes from, or how it's been filtered or sanitised. See my comment: _if your data is trustworthy..._

Comment: @MikeW Sorry if I seem paranoid, but I've had my share of pain with "evil queries", so I think it's a good idea to seal any and every risky crack in the code. Quoting from [here](http://bobby-tables.com/about.html): *"There is only one way to avoid 'Bobby Tables' attacks: 1. Do not create SQL statements that include outside data. 2. Use parameterized SQL calls. That's it. Don't try to escape invalid characters. Don't try to do it yourself. Learn how to use parameterized statements. Always, every single time."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mike W (Thank you), I changed

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

for

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
     // Success
}
```